# How to validate and parse date in C?

Tags: c

I'm getting this date as invalid "006.010.002021" and my question is, how can I validate it and convert it to "06.10.2021"

thank you in advance

```
int isDateValid(sDate date)
{
    int daysPerMonth;

    switch (date.month)
    {
    case 1:
    case 2:
        daysPerMonth = 28;
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
    case 11:
        daysPerMonth = 30;
        break;
    case 12:
        daysPerMonth = 31;
        break;
    default:
        return 0;
    }

    if ((daysPerMonth == 28) && isLeapYear(date.year))
        daysPerMonth++;

    if (date.day > daysPerMonth || date.day <= 0 || date.day > 2117 || date.year < 1917)
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the posted code have to do with your question?

Comment: BTW: december is not the only month with 31 days, and january has not 28 days.

Comment: Also consider what happens if the last condition is false. What value do you return then? BTW what is `sDate`?

Comment: date.day > 2117 ? (Mostly date.year) also function return nothing when day is valid.

Comment: @PtitXav ohh I didn't mean to write date.day

Comment: @Jabberwocky I didn't mean to assign 28 to january and sDate is a struct for date(day, month, year)

Comment: @WhozCraig I thought that I needed to implement it there, but I guess that I'm wrong

Comment: @Mysterion don't describe your code but rather show it. Actually you should show a [mcve]

Comment: Please do not switch questions with fully different issues, post another question instead.

Comment: @Devolus my bad sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strptime()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) to read a string into a date/time format. However, you can only check if the string failed or not, it will not tell you what is wrong and how to fix it.

The best way to handle a wrong date is to throw an error informing the user that the date is wrong, because your code can not fix it.

Your `case 1:` will assign 28 days to january as well and the other cases will also yield wrong days per month.

```
switch (date.month)
{
case 2:
    daysPerMonth = 28;
    break;
case 4:
case 6:
case 9:
case 11:
    daysPerMonth = 30;
    break;
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 8:
case 10:
case 12:
    daysPerMonth = 31;
    break;
default:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting the switch case. The output should be like that: Please enter a valid date: 006.010.002021
The date 06.10.2021 is valid!

Comment: Parsing dates is rather complicated. And you didn't say if you expect only this particular format, or any format. If it is just this format, you can easily pares each int on it's own and validate it, though there is more to it to do it properly if it is supposed to be a generic date routine.